# Как проверять залитые пользователями файлы на вируcы

Tags: вирусы

Здравствуйте, например есть у каждого пользователя возможность заливать файлы (картинки, видео, аудио и текст). Вопрос: как проверять залитые файлы пользователям на вирусы моментально, чтоб сайт работал стабильно?

Как справляются большие проекты с этим?

Comment: Никак, большие проекты этим не заморачивают себе голову. И полный маразм - это проверять картинки, аудио, видео на вирусы.

Comment: и как они решают эту проблему например если вирус попал?

Comment: @bemulima смысл вируса в том, что он должен как-то еще запуститься. Картинки, видео и т.п. - это не исполняемые файлы. По сути они сначала проходят какую-то обработку сторонними программами.

Comment: Как один из вариантов http://www.kaspersky.ru/anti-virus-linux-file-server однако ни малейшего понятия как он работает, но судя по описанию должен подойти для решения вашей проблемы. При этом можно держать сам сайт на одном хосте, а файловый сервер на другом хосте и заливать пользовательский контент именно на него... ну скорее всего так и делают большие проекты :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Картинки, видео и т.п. - это не исполняемые файлы.
```

Для сервера - это просто бинарный мусор и его обработка зависит от настроек сервера. Если указать интерпретатору PHP обрабатывать jpeg, скажем, как файл сценария, то он этот файл распарсит и исполнит PHP-код, который будет там находиться (если найдет).

Гораздо перспективней видится задание соответствующих ограничений в правах доступа для загруженных файлов. А как полумеры, защиты от "хулиганов" подойдет и задание, скажем, одного, "левого" расширения для исполняемых httpd файлов, и переименование, чтобы к файлу труднее было обратититься напрямую, и проверки на расширение, и ресайзинг картинок и много чего еще.

Многое зависит от ресурсов сервера. Если Ваши ресурсы эту прихоть могут себе позволить - Virustotal, скажем, не загибается при его нагрузке от проверки файла 1000 и 1 антивирем, - то пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

На крупных проектах, как правило, делают преобразование исходного файла в нужный формат. То есть не используют закачанный файл ни в каком виде, а сразу конвертируют его в собственные форматы (для картинок - преобразуют в jpeg с нужным набором размеров, для аудио - в mp3 с различными битрейтами, для видео - в mp4 с разными разрешениями).

Если конвертация прошла успешно, то ссылку на файл добавляют в базу, если нет, то пользователю выводится ошибка.

Сканировать на вирусы имеет смысл большие файлы, размещаемые в качестве архива или файлы с пользовательскими расширениями (doc, xls, pdf и т.д.).

Также имеет смысл выделить отдельное хранилище под загрузку файлов, а не размещать его вместе с исполняемыми скриптами и базой данных сайта. Даже в случае несанкционированного доступа в хранилище хакеры все равно не смогут получить нормальный доступ к сайту.